# Undefined offset: 0 in Guzzle during var_dump() on json response

Tags: php, json, guzzle

I was following the documentation of Guzzle and got stuck on json response. This is my code

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client();
$response = $client->get('http://httpbin.org/get');
$json = $response->json();
var_dump($json[0]['origin']);
```

When I run this file I get the error

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\guzzle\config.php on line 8
NULL
```

Why am I getting undefined offset?

Comment: What is returned when you just do `var_dump($json)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previous stack overflow questions that can provide this same question and answer, can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25393915/php-notice-undefined-offset-0) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549561/notice-undefined-offset-0-in).

From the [Guzzle Docs](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/http-messages.html#id2):

> Guzzle uses the json_decode() method of PHP and uses arrays rather than stdClass objects for objects.

PHP is trying to access the key 0 of the $json array.  Instead of finding a value it encounters an undefined offset for [0] and throws the error.